# Fetching resources programmatically based on previous response

Tags: gatling

I need to generate load test on a REST web service. One endpoint of it works in a way that the client needs to post some data, then it starts some background tasks and returns a set of dynamic resource URLs that need to be queried *in parallel* to get the end results of the background tasks. I come up with something like this:

```scala
http("service request with arbitrary nr of returned resources")
    .post("/someService") // post, params omitted for clarity
    .check(jsonPath(...).saveAs("resourceLinks")) //
    .resources(
        // loop trough resourceLinks saved at previous check
        http("resource-1").get("/resource-1"), 
        http("resource-2").get("/resource-2"),
        ...
    )
```

The obvious issue with this is that requests within `.resource` need to be dynamic, and the number of returned resources may also vary based on configuration / input parameters.

It would be relatively easy if gatling had a `.resources(session => {..})` variant, but unfortunately it doesn't. Is there another way to implement such parallel resource requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not currently possible.

Comment: Gatling is very unflexible.